# Service not registered: com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.CustomTabsManager$1@4af7a6e

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal

I am using msal library in an android app and this crash is occurring on many devices

My user agent cannot be WEBVIEW

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.CustomTabsManager$1@4af7a6e
       at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1160)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1475)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
       at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.CustomTabsManager.unbind(CustomTabsManager.java:164)
       at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.BrowserAuthorizationStrategy.dispose(BrowserAuthorizationStrategy.java:182)
       at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.BrowserAuthorizationStrategy.completeAuthorization(BrowserAuthorizationStrategy.java:157)
       at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.LocalMSALController.completeAcquireToken(LocalMSALController.java:258)
       at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.commands.InteractiveTokenCommand.notify(InteractiveTokenCommand.java:77)
       at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.completeInteractive(CommandDispatcher.java:608)
       at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.access$1100(CommandDispatcher.java:83)
       at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher$4$1.onReceive(CommandDispatcher.java:565)
       at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
       at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

here's my json config file.

```
  "client_id": "client_id",
  "authorization_user_agent": "BROWSER",
  "account_mode": "MULTIPLE",
  "redirect_uri": "redirect_uri",
  "authorities": [
    {
      "type": "B2C",
      "authority_url": "authority_url",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "B2C",
      "authority_url": "authority_url"
    }
  ],
  "browser_safelist": [
    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.mi.globalbrowser",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "g7zGEnZipieE6ZyBA4Bz00kxU8h0F9QTwPLL-dnRVwngI0FJWJiD3rCEJsIQ_VK064SNdxzqggnnnAqT8LI89A=="
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's a list of some devices where the crash occurs

**moto g(6) play**

**moto z3 play**

**Moto G(4) Plus**

**LG K40S**

**LG Q60**

**ZenFone Max Shot (ZB634KL)**

and many other not listed here, including xiaomi, samsgung and onePlus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated MSAL to version 2.2.1 and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the known bug in the [microsoft-authentication-library-for-android](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1539).

You can authenticate by edit the `auth_config.json` file in the Raw folder and change the user agent to this `authorized_user_agent` : `WEBVIEW`.

You can authenticate the user using the Webview instead of the browser and from this way your app will not be crashed.

Look into this [pull-request](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-common-for-android/pull/1549/files).

Comment: Hi! Thank yoiu for your comment.

As I said, my user agent cannot be webview because the social login.

Comment: This is known bug:  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1539

Also here is a pull-request as a solution please take a look at this. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-common-for-android/pull/1549

Comment: Thanks for replying, the person who had opened this issue is my teammate. I already updated my MSAL to the latest version and now everything is working fine. Thanks again for your support :D